# How can I spilt a text field input so I can calculate median, mode mean and Standard Deviation of the data?

Tags: javascript, function, mean, median

I want to calculate the median, mode, Mean and Standard Deviation of the datain in javascript but I couldn't spilt my input in the textfields so it would be like this 1 2 3 4 5 instead of 12345.

I have tried split method but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
function mean(values) {
  var total = 0,
    i, results;
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
    total += values[i];
  }
  results = total / values.length;
  document.getElementById("meanOutput").innerHTML = results;
}

function mode() {
  document.getElementById("modeOutput").innerHTML = "Fahad!";
}

function median() {
  document.getElementById("medianOutput").innerHTML = "Nasser";
}

function stdv() {
  document.getElementById("stdvOutput").innerHTML = "Alqahtani";
}
```

```html
Mean: <input type="text" id="meanText"> Median:
<input type="text" id="medianText"> Mode:
<input type="text" id="ModeText"> Standard Deviation of the data:<input type="text" id="STDV">

<p id="meanOutput"></p>
<p id="modeOutput"></p>
<p id="medianOutput"></p>
<p id="stdvOutput"></p>



<button onclick="mean(document.getElementById('meanText').value); median(); mode(); stdv();">Calculate</button>
```

I expect that the text-fields input accepts 1 2 3 4 5 and calculate it instead of displaying `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to type conversion that is string type to integer, you need to parse your input numbers so that you can perform mathematical calculations, and
Before type conversion 
you need to convert your input(different numbers with space separated, Eg-22 23 24) to a array of substrings which can be achieved using split function in javascript. Particularly in your case you need to split on the basis of spaces in your inputs.
Rest is all good in your code.

Hope, this helps you out.

Code change will only be

```
    function mean(values) {
       var total = 0,
       i, results;
       var arraySubstrings = values.split(' ');
       for (i = 0; i < arraySubstrings.length; i += 1) {
          total += parseInt(arraySubstrings[i]);
       }

    results = total / arraySubstrings.length;   
    document.getElementById("meanOutput").innerHTML = results;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. The problem was somehow related to type coercion. You are receiving a string as an argument, then you're iterating over every single character of the string and "adding" them (that means you are concatenating chars, not adding numbers. To add numbers, you have to first parse them `parseInt()`). At the end, when you do the division, JS automatically 'transforms' your string into a number (this only happens for division and multiplication. When adding or subtracting, JS will do the opposite, transforming numbers into strings instead). This kind of strange things happens when you work combining multiple data types.

```js
function mean(values) {
  var total = 0,
    i, results;
  var onlyNumbers = values.split(/\D/);
  for (i = 0; i < onlyNumbers.length; i += 1) {
    total += parseInt(onlyNumbers[i]);
  }
  results = total / onlyNumbers.length;
  document.getElementById("meanOutput").innerHTML = results;
}

function mode() {
  document.getElementById("modeOutput").innerHTML = "Fahad!";
}

function median() {
  document.getElementById("medianOutput").innerHTML = "Nasser";
}

function stdv() {
  document.getElementById("stdvOutput").innerHTML = "Alqahtani";
}
```

```html
Mean: <input type="text" id="meanText"> Median:
<input type="text" id="medianText"> Mode:
<input type="text" id="ModeText"> Standard Deviation of the data:<input type="text" id="STDV">

<p id="meanOutput"></p>
<p id="modeOutput"></p>
<p id="medianOutput"></p>
<p id="stdvOutput"></p>



<button onclick="mean(document.getElementById('meanText').value); median(); mode(); stdv();">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: I test this number: 11 4 5 6 66 and it gives me 4.142857142857143 instead of 18.4 which is the correct result

Comment: @ThFriendOFWolf I've just copied/pasted the number and it returns 18.4, could you re-check please?

Comment: @ThFriendOFWolf 4.142857142857143 is the result for "1 1 4 5 6 6 6" as input, 18.4 is the result for "11 4 5 6 66"

Comment: my friend the problem has been solved, I'm stuck right now with median, mode and STDV, can you help?